# Change pop up 'email has been sent' to bootstrap 'contextual background'?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, email

I have a pop up on my website that lets the user know that the email has been sent.

I want to change that to a nicer message via bootstrap (website is made from bootstrap)

Instead of a pop up message, I'd like a contexual background. 
You can see them here: Contextual backgrounds
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

This is what the popup code looks like.

> if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, $attachments)) {    echo
>   'The message was sent. Check your email inbox.'; } else {
>       echo 'The message was not sent!'; };
>       enter code here

What do I need to do to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can echo html code with PHP:

```
if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, $attachments)) { 
    echo '<p class="bg-success">The message was sent. Check your email inbox.</p>'; 
} 
else { 
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">The message was not sent!</p>'; };
}
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work. It just turns the pop up into saying: <p class="bg-success">The message was sent. Check your email inbox.</p>

Comment: Yes, could you please post the HTML of your popver? You'll probably need to change that

Comment: Sorry where would I find that? I don't think there is any html for it. It's a browser based popup. Here's what it looks like now: http://imgur.com/qjWf6xt

Comment: You are using JS alert(); that can't be styled. no way around that, you should make a div to show or a modal instead, that would be perfectly customizable